# Knockout JS removeAll() fails the second time it is called

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

In my view model I have a couple of methods that reset the data in an observable array. Everything works fine the first time I click a the button which calls the `newGame` method.  However, the second time I click the button I get a javascript error.

```
    self.newGame = function () {
        // reset the zones
        self.resetBoardState();

        // more stuff here but clipped for brevity ...
    }

    self.resetBoardState = function () {
        // clear all zones...
        self.library.removeAll();

        // place all cards in deck into library ...
        self.library = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(self.deck));
    }
```

The error I'm getting in the javascript console is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'removeAll'
```

**I have a [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zrHEn/2/) here so the whole view model can be seen.**  If you click the "New Game" button the first time everything works perfectly.  You can also click the "Draw a Card" button and it behaves properly as well.  However, clicking "Mulligan" button causes the same error as clicking "New Game" again.

What can I do to get this functional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.library` is originally an observableArray, but your reset turns it into a plain array. Instead, just set the value of the existing observable.

replace the line

`self.library = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(self.deck));`

with

`self.library(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(self.deck)));`